# SQL server function how to use parameter to in query

Tags: sql-server, sql-function

my sql function is not working parameter value. If provide hard code value it will give me results.

```
ALTER function [dbo].[team_concat] (@input varchar)
returns varchar(8000)
as
BEGIN
declare @putout varchar(8000)
set @putout = null

-- select @putout = COALESCE(IsNull(@putout+ ', ', ''), '') + team_residence_location from programs where team_combo = 'Hartford CIS / Coaching'
select @putout = COALESCE(IsNull(@putout+ ', ', ''), '') + team_residence_location from programs where team_combo = @input


return @putout
```

Comment: Your parameter data length would be 1 char only as you don't have specify the data lenght.

Comment: my bad!! silly one. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    ALTER function [dbo].[team_concat] (@input varchar(100))  --- specify length
    returns varchar(8000)
    as
    BEGIN
    declare @putout varchar(8000)
    set @putout = null

    -- select @putout = COALESCE(IsNull(@putout+ ', ', ''), '') + team_residence_location from programs where team_combo = 'Hartford CIS / Coaching'
    select @putout = COALESCE(IsNull(@putout+ ', ', ''), '') + team_residence_location from programs where team_combo = @input


    return @putout
```